# will APNS generate new device token every time for a single device?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, apple-push-notifications, token

I want to know that does apple's Push Notification Server generate new device token every time when requesting from a same device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generally it will not, but under some circumstances it might change tokens. That is why you should always have your app query the OS for the token each time it launches.

Answer (score 0):

Not every time, but apple may change a token.